# how to insert all keys of array in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a array which always the number of its keys divided by 4 is integer *(in oder words, mod is 0. for example in below example: `[12 , 4] {div = 3 | mod = 0}`)*.

My array is something like this:

```
$arr = Array
(
    [0] =>  'zero',
    [1] =>  'one',
    [2] =>  'two',
    [3] =>  'three',
    [4] =>  'four',
    [5] =>  'five',
    [6] =>  'six',
    [7] =>  'seven',
    [8] =>  'eight',
    [9] =>  'nine',
    [10] =>  'ten',
    [11] =>  'eleven'
);
```

Now I have a table with 4 column and I want to put all keys of my array into my table. In fact I want to insert each 4 keys of the array in 1 row of table. something like this:

```
// mytable

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  col1   |  col2   |  col3   |  col4   |
|---------------------------------------| 
|  zero   |   one   |   two   |  three  |
|  four   |   five  |   six   |  seven  |
|  eight  |   nine  |   ten   |  eleven |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried before asking and I concluded that I should use nested `for(){}`. Unfortunately, in reality my array has 1000 keys, and for this reason I can't do it manually. I know only the second `for(){}`:

```
for($i; I dont know the condition; $i++){
    for ($j=0;$j<=3;$j++){ // selects 4 keys
        $arr[$j];
        }
     INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3]);  // mysql codes 
    }
```

I know my codes are wrong, And please if you can help me. thanks

Comment: `$myArray = array_chunk($myArray, 4); foreach($myArray as $fourValues) { ....do insert of $fourValues here }`

Comment: isn't this question asked here 400 times daily

Comment: thats one terrible db schema

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, I don't know `array_chunk()` before. anyway thanks.

Comment: i have never seen the need for modula 4 division to determine which row it goes into. but today is a new day

Comment: @MarkBaker Used with permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need a nested for. One is enough:

```
for ($j=0; $j<=count($array); $j+= ){ // selects 4 keys
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($arr[$j],$arr[$j+1],$arr[$j+2],$arr[$j+3]);  // mysql codes 
}
```

$j += 4; is the same as $j = $j + 4; it increases counter by 4.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: To the person who edited my answer: Please don't add things to my solution. It's much better if you add your own answer. Then if people think it's better than mine you can receive the credit you deserve. If I accepted your edit and people liked your code, the credit would have been credited to me.

Comment: Thanks again pal. that was useful for me.